Are the minimal nondegenerate extensions universal?
We reference [EGNO] for the concept of a braided fusion category. Following the conventions in [JFR], let $\mathcal{C}$ denote a braided fusion category equipped with a braiding $\beta$, and let $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{C}$ represent a fully faithful inclusion of braided fusion categories. The centralizer of this inclusion is defined as:
$$\mathcal{Z}_2 (\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{C}) := \{ y \in \mathcal{C} \ | \ \beta_{y,x} \circ \beta_{x,y} = {\rm id}_{x \otimes y} \ \forall x \in \mathcal{B} \}.$$
The Müger center $\mathcal{Z}_2 (\mathcal{B})$ of $\mathcal{B}$ is the centralizer of the identity inclusion. This center forms a symmetric fusion category. A braided fusion category $\mathcal{B}$ is termed nondegenerate if $\mathcal{Z}_2 (\mathcal{B})$ is equivalent to the trivial fusion category ${\rm Vec}$. A minimal nondegenerate extension of a braided fusion category $\mathcal{B}$ is an inclusion $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ is nondegenerate and the canonical inclusion $\mathcal{Z}_2 (\mathcal{B}) \subset \mathcal{Z}_2 (\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M})$ is an equivalence. This concept was introduced by Müger in [Mu]. A minimal nondegenerate extension is not guaranteed to exist, and when one does, it may not be unique. We are curious about their universality in the context outlined below:
Question: Given a fully faithful inclusion $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{C}$ of braided fusion categories with $\mathcal{C}$ being nondegenerate, and assuming $\mathcal{B}$ allows for minimal nondegenerate extensions, is there a minimal nondegenerate extension $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{C}$?

References
[EGNO] Etingof, Pavel; Gelaki, Shlomo; Nikshych, Dmitri; Ostrik, Victor. Tensor categories. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, 205. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2015. xvi+343 pp.
[JFR] Johnson-Freyd, Theo; Reutter, David. Minimal nondegenerate extensions. J. Amer. Math. Soc. 37 (2024), no. 1, 81--150.
[Mu] Müger, Michael. On the structure of modular categories. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 87 (2003), no. 2, 291--308.

No.
Recall that if $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{C}$ is an inclusion of nondegenerate braided fusion categories, then $\mathcal{C}$ factors as $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{M} \boxtimes \mathcal{Z}_2(\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{C})$ with $\mathcal{Z}_2(\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{C})$ nondegenerate. If on the other hand $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M}$ is a degenerate braided subcategory (with $\mathcal{M}$ nondegenerate), then there is not a factorization of categories, but there is a factorization of Frobenius–Perron dimensions $\operatorname{FPdim}(\mathcal{M}) = \operatorname{FPdim}(\mathcal{B}) \operatorname{FPdim}(\mathcal{Z}_2(\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M}))$. It then follows from dimensions that if you have $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{C}$ with $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{C}$, then the inclusion
$$ \mathcal{Z}_2(\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M}) \boxtimes \mathcal{Z}_2(\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{Z}_2(\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{C})$$
is an iso.
Set $\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{Z}_2(\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{C})$. It admits a minimal nondegenerate extension if and only if $\mathcal{B}$ does (because we understand the obstruction theory).
If $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M}$ is a minimal extension, then $\mathcal{Z}_2(\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{M})$ is symmetric, and is the common Müger centre of $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{D}$. Thus we would find a factorization
$$\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{Z}_2(\mathcal{D}) \boxtimes (\text{nondegenerate}).$$
Thus to give a counterexample, it suffices to give a braided fusion category which admits a minimal nondegenerate extension but which does not factor as $(\text{centre}) \boxtimes (\text{nondegenerate})$. Such categories are commonplace. Here is an example. Take the nondegenerate category $\mathrm{SL}(2)_4$. The simple objects are indexed by the representations of $\mathrm{SL}(2)$ of spins $j = 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2$; let me write $V_j$ for the object of spin $j$. Then $V_0 = 1$ is the unit object and $V_2$ is an invertible boson. For $\mathcal{D}$, take the centralizer of $V_2$. The inclusion $\mathcal{D} \subset \mathrm{SL}(2)_4$ is a minimal nondegenerate extension. This category $\mathcal{D}$ is sometimes called the "even half" of $\mathrm{SL}(2)_4$; it consists of the objects of spin $0, 1, 2$. The fusion rules are $V_2^2 = V_0$, $V_2 V_1 = V_1$, and $V_1^2 = V_0 + V_1 + V_2$. Thus $\mathcal{D}$ does not factor as $(\text{centre}) \boxtimes (\text{nondegenerate})$.

The fact that the degenerate braided fusion category $\mathcal{D}$ does not factor as  $(\text{centre}) \boxtimes (\text{nondegenerate})$ implies that it is not its own centre, i.e. it is not symmetric. But according to the rules you wrote, $\mathcal{D}$ is Grothendieck equivalent to ${\rm Rep}(S_3)$. This contradicts the paragraph 4.4 in the paper "Pre-modular categories of rank 3" by Victor Ostrik, stating that a braided fusion category Grothendieck equivalent to ${\rm Rep}(S_3)$ must be symmetric.

Victor only writes "It is easy to see that $\tilde{S}$-matrix for such category necessarily has rank 1 and hence any braided structure on $\mathcal{C}$ is symmetric." I do not find this easy to see. But I might have the wrong fusion rules. You can surely compute the $SL(2)_4$ fusion rules and check.

The fusion data and modular data are available at: https://anyonwiki.github.io/pages/FRPages/FR_5_1_0_3.html

According to the modular data written there, you are right! There is a braided non-symmetric fusion category Grothendieck equivalent to ${\rm Rep}(S_3)$.
